# Having issues distributing third party iOS app

Tags: ios, distribution, enterprise

I am very new to iOS development and am in a bit of a bind. Another company has made an app for us and we are to deploy it. I have an enterprise development account and have successfully deployed one of my own apps to my own secured app store.

I have received a .ipa and a .plist file from company B and tried to put it up on my app store as I did with my app using the special href tag.

`a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://www.myurl.com/app/company_b.plist">link</a>`

The app downloads about 90% then fails. I have ensured that it is a valid plist file pointing to the .ipa.

Company-B had to add my iOS device to their device list at https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/deviceList.action. After they did this the app would download correctly.

I need to deploy this app to a number of people and Company B cannot add all the devices to their device list.

What can I do to deploy this app properly?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you need to re-sign the ipa with your enterprise certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a script like https://gist.github.com/RichardBronosky/2878446 to re-sign the ipa with your enterprise certificate. This way you don't need to give the 3rd party developer your signing identity.

You should **never** give out the private key for your enterprise certificate or give developer.apple.com access to **anyone** outside of your company.

Comment: This script didn't work for me but it eventually led me to an answer that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The company has not properly signed the application. Get them to rebundle the ipa with the proper enterprise certificate